# How to incorporate Oauth2.0 in existing Java Spring web MVC and REST project?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization, okta

I have a Dynamic web application having Java as backend (spring web MVC jars + REST jars) controlled by one Authentication Servlet and one Controller servlet for other functions in app.
It has java script & html as frontend.
The project has WebContent folder which has rest-servlet.xml and web.xml in it with other frontend files.

Now I need to implement Oauth2.0 replacing the SSO in the Authentication Servlet. In below code instead of getting details from header I am supposed to utilize a JSON response from OAuth2.0 process implementation code.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
String digest  = req.getHeader("Authorization");//need to remove this

//Pull PXED headers
String id = req.getHeader("IAMUSERID"); //need to remove this
String firstName = req.getHeader("IAMUSERFIRSTNAME"); //need to remove this
String lastName = req.getHeader("IAMUSERLASTNAME");//need to remove this
String groups = req.getHeader("IAMUSERGROUPMEMBERSHIP");//need to remove this

}
```

Now PXED team has provided me steps to get this JSON response in POSTMAN. Steps they provided:

1. Set Grant type as **Authorization Code** Set the authorization type as
   **Oauth2.0**
2. Set the **callback URL** (which is the dev url of my app)
3. Set **Authorization URL** provided by the PXED team
4. Set **Token URL** provided by the PXED team
5. Set **Client ID** provided by the PXED team - **APP_client**
6. Set **Client Secret** provided by the PXED team
7. Click on "Get new Access Token"
8. Copy the token and Paste this token to the end of another long URL
9. Set **POST** as HTTP method for the last step URL and Change authorization type to **Basic Auth.**
10. Set the username & password as provided by the PXED team- **APP_validate & password**
11. Send the request
12. JSON response is received with all the details.

So far I have explored and failed with :

1. Spring Boot Security ( I cannot implement this as I cannot change the architecture)
2. Nimbus OAuth 2.0 SDK with OpenID Connect : https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/oauth/token-request
3. Apache OLTU (this is retired but I was still not able to set the right details in object): https://oltu.apache.org/apidocs/oauth2/reference/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/package-summary.html

I need to implement this code in backend only.
Please help me with the right and secure library to implement OAuth2.0.
Also, If you are familiar with the NIMBUS OAUTH 2.0 SDK, can you help me set the details in the steps in right classes?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [gateway to handle the OAuth dance](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/08/secure-legacy-spring-cloud-gateway) for you, then your application only needs to verify an access token (a "resource server" in OAuth terms).

That linked post uses Spring Cloud Gateway, but other gateways/proxies work the same way. (The post also uses a servlet filter, which could be simplified by the framework you are using).